# How to whitelist certain IP addresses to grant access to EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**AWS Beginner here**

I recently hosted an EC2 instance of timescaledb (postgresql) on my AWS.

I would like to know if it is possible to restrict the access to this db from outside.

Assuming there are 3 people who must have access to this db and are trying to access this instance and have the following IP addresses:

- The IP address of person1 is: `XXX.XX.XX.XXX`
- The IP address of person2 is: `YYY.YY.YY.YYY`
- The IP address of person3 is: `ZZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZ`

I would like to make sure that only these 3 IP addresses are given permission to access the instance and anyother IP address are not.

In other words, I would like to 'white list' the above mentioned 3 IP addresses and 'Black list' all the other IP addresses.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using Security Groups Inbound rules:

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html#creating-security-group

To create a new security group using the console

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups.
3. Choose Create Security Group.
4. Specify a name and description for the security
   group.
5. For VPC, choose the ID of the VPC.
6. You can start adding
   rules, or you can choose Create to create the security group now
   (you can always add rules later). For more information about adding
   rules, see Adding Rules to a Security Group.

Comment: Hey, thanks.. I will have a look at it. I also have a follow-up question. Now, as the IP address of a person changes dynamically, is there a possibility to take that into consideration?

Comment: you can have a VPN as a bridge between your users and EC2 server. This way it doesn't matter where user is connecting from, as long as they do it via VPN they will always connect from the same IP. But you'd probably want it to be your own managed VPN solution so you can define this static outbound VPN

Comment: disclaimer, i'm not expert on vpn setup, but this could be a good starting point https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-connection-vpc/